# config.assets.compile = false - makes heroku not display my images in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

So I'm trying to make my Rails app as fast as possible and I read here that if I turned config.assets.compile to false. When it was true and I pushed code through the terminal the script in the terminal would say that having that set = true could affect the performance of my app.

Anyway, now that I turned that to false, none of my images are displaying.
Here my production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://TODO_PUT_YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE" }
      # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
      config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # Code is not reloaded between requests.
      config.cache_classes = true
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
      # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
      # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
      # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
      config.eager_load = true

      # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

      # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
      # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
      # config.require_master_key = true

      # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
      # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
      config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

      # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

      # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
      config.assets.compile = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
      # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

      # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
      # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

      # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

      # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
      config.active_storage.service = :local

      # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
      # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
      # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
      # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

      # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
      # config.force_ssl = true

      # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
      # when problems arise.
      config.log_level = :debug

      # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
      config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
      config.serve_static_assets = true


      # Use a different cache store in production.
      # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

      # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
      # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
      # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "Hoxton-Technologica_#{Rails.env}"

      config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

      # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
      # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
      # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
      # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true

      # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

      # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
      config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

      # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
      # require 'syslog/logger'
      # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

      if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
        logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
        logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
        config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
      end

      # Do not dump schema after migrations.
      config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    end
```

and here is my development.rb

```
      Rails.application.configure do
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://localhost:3000" }
      # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
      config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = true
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
      # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
      # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
      config.cache_classes = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Do not eager load code on boot.
      config.eager_load = false

      # Show full error reports.
      config.consider_all_requests_local = true

      # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
      # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
      if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

        config.cache_store = :memory_store
        config.public_file_server.headers = {
          'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
        }
      else
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

        config.cache_store = :null_store
      end

      # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
      config.active_storage.service = :local

      # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

      # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :log

      # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
      config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

      # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
      config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

      # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
      # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
      # number of complex assets.
      config.assets.debug = false

      # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
      config.assets.quiet = true

      # Raises error for missing translations
      # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

      # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
      # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
      config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
    end
```

I have turned the config.assets.compile to false, pushed to production and run the following in the terminal:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

My images are still not displayed and this is what the terminal displays:

```
/Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core- 
2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required 
arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:22:in `new'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:126:in `eager_load_fog'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:139:in `fog_credentials='
from /Users/CHAFET/code/godiaz/Hoxton-Technologica/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:161:in `configure'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
from /Users/CHAFET/code/godiaz/Hoxton-Technologica/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<main>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `block in load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
from /Users/CHAFET/code/godiaz/Hoxton-Technologica/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
/Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core- 
2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required 
arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core- 
2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core- 
2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:22:in `new'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:126:in `eager_load_fog'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:139:in `fog_credentials='
from /Users/CHAFET/code/godiaz/Hoxton-Technologica/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:161:in `configure'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
from /Users/CHAFET/code/godiaz/Hoxton-Technologica/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<main>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `block in load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `load'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
from /Users/CHAFET/code/godiaz/Hoxton-Technologica/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/CHAFET/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the value to `true` will compile the assets for each request. When set to `false` , you need to ensure your assets are already precompiled.

You can do so by running the following command before starting your server in production mode:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

`clobber` will remove the precompiled assets from the public directory and `precompile` will compile the assets and store them in the public directory.

Hope this helped.

Comment: so I set config.assets.compile = false, push to production and then in my terminal I run those 2 commands but it still doesnt work. When running the 2 commands this is displayed. I have edited the text above.

Comment: The error you got is related to your configuration of Fog gem. You might not have passed valid keys for production configuration. You need to fix it before starting a production environment.